# No success when trying to login on a page using Protractor: no error is pointed but the same page is loaded

Tags: javascript, authentication, protractor

I am beginner in using protractor. I am just trying to do a page logon in a non angular page. I tried many solutions/workarounds, the last one was based on the following link:

http://agiletesters.com.br/topic/71/protractor-page-objects-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-metodo/7

Basically, i have two files: conf.js and login.js (see codes further). I execute the following command (in my prompt, os windows): 
protractor conf.js

// Code conf.js =>

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: ['login.js'],
    directConnect: true
}
```

---

// Code login.js =>

```
    describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
         browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;
         var originalTimeout;

    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 100000;
        browser.driver.get('http://www.maisbolao.com.br');
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });

    it('should fill user and password and logins', function() {

        var loginNameInputElm = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="Email"]')); 
        var passwordInputElm = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="Senha"]'));
        var loginBtnElm = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="form-login"]'));
        loginNameInputElm.sendKeys('login');//i omitted the login and password information just for security reasons
        passwordInputElm.sendKeys('password');

        loginBtnElm.click();
    });

    it('reach?', function() {
        console.log("browser.driver.getCurrentUrl(): "+browser.driver.getCurrentUrl());
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);
    });

});
```

I also tried to use the addCookie function with the JSESSIONID cookie value, but the same message below was displayed and the same behaviour observed.

The message protractor gives to me is: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are some issue in your code:

```
it('reach?', function() {
    browser.sleep(5000); 
    // sleep 5s to wait page load after click login button for debug purpose
    // should replace to browser.wait()

    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
       console.log("browser.driver.getCurrentUrl(): " + url);
    });
    // browser.getCurrentUrl() return a promise
    // you should consume the eventual value of promise inside then()       

    browser.sleep(5000);

 });
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response....i did the modification you suggested but an error is presented... "Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined... " . Even when i add "browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;", the error remains.

Comment: I think you should use `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`,  Why you not use `browser` directly, but use `browser.drive`.  The `browser` is wrapped for Angular app,  Even it inherit most API from `driver`, but ignoreSynchronization is not a property of `driver`, So don't use `browser.driver` casually.

Comment: yes, i am using browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true; (see second line of the code). I am using browser.driver because the initial pages of my application are not in angular and protractor documentation recommends to use browser.driver in this case. See: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api-overview

Comment: in protractor inside code, it won't to read `browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization`, I think will only read `browser.ignoreSynchronization`. If you assign `ignoreSynchronization = true` on `driver`,  `browser.ignoreSynchronization` still be `false`, so protractor still think your page is angular page.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot there is some warnings but your 2 tests passed (2 specs 0 failures).

If your test fails you will have red F instead of green dot.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.... Yes, the tests apparently passed. The problem is, as the same page is loaded, i am unable to get the fields of the next page (after the login) to continue my tests...